# Drop Primary Key In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I receive this error when I try to drop Primary Key From my Table:

```
00:44:25    ALTER TABLE BOOKS DROP PRIMARY KEY  Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key 0.000 sec.
```

Below is my code

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS BD3;   
USE BD3;

# creare tabele Carti si Library

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books(
id TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
titlu VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
autor VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
data_aparitie DATE NOT NULL,
editura VARCHAR(15),
gen ENUM('drama', 'SF') NOT NULL

);

ALTER TABLE Books DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: An AI has to be a (component of) a PK

Comment: Why are you removing the primary key?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Answer (score 6):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has to be a key. So if you want to remove the primary key index, you first have to remove this option.

```
ALTER TABLE Books MODIFY id TINYINT NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: A little correction: The AI column has to be member of **a** key, not necessarily the *primary* key (as the message says). Depending on the storage engine it might need to be the first column in that key.

Comment: The table apparently has no other keys.

Comment: Didn't say it had. But that doesn't change that the key the AI column is a member of doesn't need to be (designated as) primary.

Comment: And although it doesn't have to be the PK, it's almost nonsense for it not to be.

Comment: The AI column could be the leftmost column of a non-null UNIQUE KEY, which is basically a de facto primary key. But I agree if the auto-increment column is only part of a non-unique key, that's dubious. I've never seen a legitimate use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message explains it a AUTO_INCREMENT column has to be a key, so you have to remove both

What you can do

Is first remove auto_incement and Proiary Key from the table

DROP The index and then afterwards add KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books (
    id TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titlu VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    autor VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    data_aparitie DATE NOT NULL,
    editura VARCHAR(15),
    gen ENUM('drama', 'SF') NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE books
  MODIFY id TINYINT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE Books DROP PRIMARY KEY;

ALTER TABLE books
  MODIFY id TINYINT NOT NULL  KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: A little correction: The AI column has to be member of **a** key, not necessarily the *primary* key (as the message says). Depending on the storage engine it might need to be the first column in that key.